# HTML not rendering server side variable in Express JS

Tags: html, node.js, express, rendering, pug

I passed an array from my client side Javascript to my server js and it worked. Now, I am trying to pass this array from server js to HTML but it is not working. So my server js is successfully passing the variable (it is visible in network tab in my browser) but my browser source code is not showing its value and it is blank.

Here is how I am passing it to html from the backend:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/result', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('filter route hit!');
  var myArray = req.body.all_filter_value;
  console.log(myArray);
  //res.render('layout', { test: myArray });
  res.status(200).render('layout', {test: 'Simple Text'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting "myArray" from client side JS and I actually want to pass this to HTML but just to test I am passing "Simple Text". Here is how I am receiving it in html which is using pug in this case:

```
doctype html
html
  head

    link(href='/stylesheets/styles.css' rel='stylesheet')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    title Home Page
  body
    .result_window
      h1 Here is the result!
      h1= test
    .Header
```

so I can see "Here is the result!" in the browser but not the value inside "test".

This is a snippet from my browser source code and "test" is coming as blank.

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link href="[/stylesheets/styles.css](http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/styles.css)" rel="stylesheet"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>Home Page</title></head><body><div class="result_window"><h1>Here is the movie!</h1>**<h1></h1>**</div>

What am I missing?

I tried using different formats for printing the value of "test" in HTML but none worked. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. h1 <%= test %> //prints as it is
2. h1 { test } //prints as it is
3. h1 {{ test }} //prints as it is
4. h1= test //prints nothing
5. h1= {test} //prints [object Object]

Here is my aap.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//var pug = require('pug');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var movieRouter = require('./routes/movie_filter');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', movieRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `res.render()` has a way for checking errors, adding a callback; look at [res.render docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), maybe it helps to debug

Comment: I added the callback but nothing happened. I think because there is no error in sending it. It is just not received by the browser for some reason.

Comment: Ok, the first argument to the callback is 'err'. Can you do a `console.log(err)`?

Comment: I did that and got "null"

Comment: Ok, so you are NOT sending `test` to your endpoint. Double check how and where are you sending...

Comment: I am very new to it, I am only sending and receiving "test" ones and that can be seen in the above codes. Do you think I need to rewrite everything with ejs instead of pug?

Comment: I tried to reassamble all your code, bu no luck. Where are you testing your app? Can you use a service like Stackblitz? I takes me too much time to make things work...

Comment: Ok, I finally did it. your code works well, no errors, the var `test` is being interpolated

Comment: So why is it not showing? What should I do?

Comment: Without a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how can we help? I reassembled your chunks of code, and all works well. If you publish entire project, we can see what's wrong. As an example, you can use: Stackblitz, Github, CodeSandbox

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell express.js with render engine you are using ,

You will need to tell express.js which render engine to you by specifying it in your server.js like this

I will be using ejs as my render engine

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
 
// View engine setup

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Here is an article reference https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-render-function/amp/

Comment: hi, yes I have. I will add my app.js to the question.